# Dafny assertion limitation increase?

Tags: assertion, dafny

```
predicate Contains(haystack: string, needle: string)
    ensures Contains(haystack, needle) <==> exists k :: 0 <= k <= |haystack| && needle <= haystack[k..] 
    ensures Contains(haystack, needle) <==> exists i :: 0 <= i <= |haystack| && (needle <= haystack[i..])
    ensures !Contains(haystack, needle) <==> forall i :: 0 <= i <= |haystack| ==> !(needle <= haystack[i..])
{
    if needle <= haystack then 
        assert haystack[0..] == haystack;
        true 
    else if |haystack| > 0 then 
        assert forall i :: 1 <= i <= |haystack| ==> haystack[i..] == haystack[1..][(i-1)..];
        Contains(haystack[1..], needle)
    else 
        false
}
```

Testing this predicate shows some interesting but frustrating behavior.

```
method TestContains() {
    assert Contains("aba||xx||c", "|") == true; //verifies
    assert Contains("aba||xx||c", "||") == true; //verifies
    assert Contains("aba||xx||c", "||xx||") == true; //verifies
    assert Contains("aba||xx||c", "|||") == false; //does not verify
}
```

In particular Dafny cannot evaluate whether `Contains("aba||xx||c", "|||")` is true or false. Neither assertion will verify. All obvious true examples for Contains verify quickly but any false statement with a separator of 1 letter like `Contains("aa", "b")` will verify, but with 2 letters or more it will no longer verify, like `Contains("axa", "ba")`.

Is there a way to increase the limit or otherwise convince Dafny to verify them? I tried to use {:fuel X} but it did not seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to convince Dafny:

```
method TestContains() {
    assert !Contains("axa", "ba") by {
      assert "ba"[0] != "xa"[0];
    }
}
```

Here's how I actually discovered this trick. I worked backwards from the failing assertion. I decided to use a `calc` to manually step through the execution of `Contains` until Dafny got stuck:

```
calc {
  Contains("axa", "ba");
  Contains("xa", "ba");        
  Contains("a", "ba");  // error: previous line might not be equal to this line
}
```

So then I started trying to prove that `Contains("xa", "ba") == Contains("a", "ba")`. Reading the code of `Contains`, we need to know that `!("ba" <= "xa")`, but Dafny can't see that either.

```
assert !("ba" <= "xa");  // error: assertion might not hold
```

So then I started trying to prove that. Since `<=` is built-in, we can't look at its definition easily (or can we? see below). But I guessed that roughly speaking it was defined as "all the characters are the same up until the end of the shorter string". So I figured, if I can show that some character is *not* the same, maybe Dafny will see it.

```
assert "ba"[0] != "xa"[0];
```

That assertion passes, and what's more, it unlocks all the other failing asserts and the whole thing verifies. Here's the state of the program as of when I first got it to verify.

```
method TestContains() {
    assert !Contains("axa", "ba") by {
      calc {
        Contains("axa", "ba");
        Contains("xa", "ba");        
        {
          assert "ba"[0] != "xa"[0];
          assert !("ba" <= "xa");
          assert "xa"[1..] == "a";
        }
        Contains("a", "ba");
      }
    }
}
```

Then I did some typical cleanup-after-debugging and got to the program at the top of this answer.

---

If you are curious, it actually is pretty easy to find the definition of `<=`. Use this command:

```
dafny /print:foo.bpl foo.dfy
```

This will generate the underlying Boogie code. (Replace `foo.dfy` with the name of your file and `foo.bpl` with your desired output file name.)

Then open `foo.bpl` in your text editor and search for the line

```
// definition axiom for _module.__default.Contains (revealed)
```

You will see an `axiom` on the next line that, among other things, calls `Seq#SameUntil`. So we've learned that that's the Boogie-level name for what Dafny calls string-`<=`.

Now search for

```
function Seq#SameUntil
```

and you will find its defining axiom:

```
axiom (forall<T> s0: Seq T, s1: Seq T, n: int :: 
  { Seq#SameUntil(s0, s1, n) } 
  Seq#SameUntil(s0, s1, n)
     <==> (forall j: int :: 
      { Seq#Index(s0, j) } { Seq#Index(s1, j) } 
      0 <= j && j < n ==> Seq#Index(s0, j) == Seq#Index(s1, j)));
```

Turns out, it's exactly what I guessed.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the in depth explanation. It is pretty counter intuitive that assert can't see that by default. 

It turns out it will verify if you do the following based on your example. 
```
    assert "axa"[0] != "ba"[0];
    assert Contains("axa", "ba") == false;
```